# How to make inserting data using QueryRunner faster?

Tags: java, java-8, oracle12c, apache-commons-dbcp

Reading data using QueryRunner is relatively quick even for large amounts of data.
However, when I go to insert the data it takes way longer. (50 records takes 10-20seconds)

I'm basically trying to read records from a set of tables on one database into another.
I can't use DB Links because I don't have permissions to create one to the other database.
I can't use Oracle's COPY TO commands because some of the fields are TIMESTAMPS which isn't supported by the COPY command.
I can't use PL/SQL because it need to be dynamic.

I'm considering creating a shell or batch script using SQL*Plus & SQL*Loader, but would prefer a java solution.

Alternatives to QueryRunner are OK, too. As long as they can insert data relatively quickly.

My guess is that QueryRunner is individually requesting each set of values in sequence instead of a single request with a bunch of input values.

Using: Java 1.8, commons-dbcp:1.4, commons-dbutils:1.7

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.BasicRowProcessor;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.ResultSetHandler;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.RowProcessor;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
```

---

```
    private final int colCount;
    private final int commitCount;
    
    private final String tableName;
    private final String insertSql;
    
    private final RowProcessor rowHandler = new BasicRowProcessor();
    private final QueryRunner devQueryRunner;
    
    @Override
    public Long handle(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        long readCount = 0;
        long writeCount = 0;
        
        Object[][] params = new Object[commitCount][colCount];
        try (Connection conn = devQueryRunner.getDataSource().getConnection()) {
            int row = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                readCount++;
                params[row++] = rowHandler.toArray(rs);
                if (row >= commitCount) {
                    insertRunner.batch(conn, insertSql, params);
                    writeCount+=row;
                    row = 0;
                }
            }
            if (row > 0) {
                devQueryRunner.batch(conn, insertSql, Arrays.copyOf(params, row));
            }
            return readCount;
        } finally {
            if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                logger.info(tableName+"[readCount="+readCount+", writeCount="+writeCount+"]");
            }
        }
    }
```

### Update #1

#### Times To write Using PreparedStatement (This is prohibitively slow):

> Read  50: 0ms
> Write 50: 1430ms
> Read  50: 0ms
> Write 50: 1899ms
> Read  50: 0ms
> Write 50: 805ms
> Read  50: 0ms
> Write 50: 377ms
> Read  50: 0ms
> Write 50: 1131ms
> Read  50: 0ms
> Write 50: 859ms
> Read  50: 0ms
> Write 50: 2131ms
> Read  50: 0ms
> Write 50: 2355ms
> Read  10000: 0ms
> Write 10000: 925584ms
> Read  10000: 0ms
> Write 10000: 604083ms

Comment: Are you sure that you measure insert time correct and there are no issues/locks in your database?

Comment: What value are you setting commitCount to? Have you tried varying this value and measuring whether this has any influence?

Comment: Here is a nice writeup about batch inserts, I would recommend the PreparedStatement method: http://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-batch-processing

Comment: Ivan - Yes I am sure.

Comment: Jonck - I've tried 20,000, 10,000, 100, & 50. The time mentioned was for 50.

Comment: Trying with preparedStatement manually. (Theoretically that is what QueryRunner should be using, but we'll see how this works.

Comment: No good. It is still prohibitively slow. takes 5-10 minutes just to write 10,000 records.